# ajax does not pass parameters in IE

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, post

I call ajax with parameters.My code in Chrome and Firefox works properly. But, internet explorer, my code does not pass parameters to method is calling in ajax.

cache=false and < meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" charset="utf-8"> are tried. But nothing.

$.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("url")',
                data: {
                    startDate: $("#StartDate").val(),
                    endDate: $("#EndDate").val()
                },
            })

I want to pass parameters value to controller just i want to do. Any idea?

Comment: Is there any error or warning message in the console of IE? If yes, please inform us about that may help us to understand the issue in better way. Your 1 line of code not giving much information and we are not able to produce the issue using it. Try to provide a detailed information about your issue like which kind of project it is? Which language you are using? Which version of IE you are using for making this test? Provide detailed steps to produce the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Agreeing here with Deepak, please provide a simplified working sample that we can see. If we can fix the sample you can apply the fix to your application.